# How to create application with following description?

Tags: android, ios, linux, windows, developer-tools

How to create an application which can be run on iOS, android, also in form of software in macOS, windows, Linux, etc.
I want to know on which platform I should create for building such application.
provided that I am a college student in 3rd year B. Tech Computer Science and want to develop this as my project in final year.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: I would suggest you to go with flutter, flutter will give you all types of applications with single code base without any extra efforts to make app compatible for different type of devices, suggested IDE is android studio for me, it's based on InteliJ or you can with JavaScript framework like Naj suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the link I have provided. What you're looking for is called Cross-Platform App Development (if I am not mistaken). You can use a programming Language like JavaScript/TypeScript with its corresponding compatible Framework like React Native with Cordova (for plug-ins for example) to develop apps which can be used by the platforms. If you look into that, youll find information about how it can be used as a Web App (so also on Windows for example).

[Information about Cross Platform App Development](https://www.netsolutions.com/insights/cross-platform-app-frameworks-in-2019/#:%7E:text=Open%2Dsource%20Cross%2DPlatform%20App%20Development%20Frameworks%20Based%20on%20Programming%20Languages)